# Calling a div that's a link in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, href

I'm having a little problem with my jQuery script.

I have a `href` link inside a div, that wasn't visible, when I hovered over it's parent div the div would become visible. This worked fine, but since the div that becomes visible had to be like a button I made the div inside the `href` since the wonderful world of html5 allow us to do this :).

But now the problem is that when I hover over the parent div it doesn't become visible anymore and I don't know how to call it, this has to be simple but I don't seem to find anything about it.

this is a part of the html:

```
<div id="evenementen" class="inforow">
    <div class="pic">
        <div class="aanwijzer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h3>EVENEMENTEN</h3>
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <a href="evenementen">
        <div class="button" style="display:none;">MEER INFO</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

As you can see the div is inside the a tag.

and this is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var div = '';
    $(".inforow").hover(erover, eraf);

    function erover() { 
        div = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#" + div).stop().animate({marginTop:0, height:325},200);
        $(this).children(".button").show();
    }

    function eraf() {
        $(this).stop().animate({marginTop:20, height:285},200);
        $(this).children(".button").hide();
    }
});
```

So I assume the .button has to be changed in something else. I've tried things like .button a and even .button a:link (although this is even more far fetched). Anyway I hope someone knows the answer, and thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using   $(".inforow").hover(erover, eraf)? Can you try using   $("#evenementen").hover(erover, eraf);?

Comment: Can you create an example jsFiddle, with the corresponding css included so we can play with that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ub3zM/ there you go, Ankur his code was right, but I posted the "wrong" code so that you start from the original problem

Comment: I'm using $(".inforow") because there are more divs with the same class on wich I want to call this, with $("#evenementen") I'm only going the call this one div that has the id evenementen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

> `$(this).find(".button").show()`

instead of

> `$(this).children(".button").show()`

The reason for this being that the div-button is no longer a direct child of the main (parent) div, but is now wrapped inside the a tag; for this reason, children() will not reach it whereas find() will.

Comment: How does that change anything?  In this particular case I thought `children()` would be a better choice as the button class is a direct child of the selected element.

Comment: Coz the button is not immediate children of the main div, hence `children` wont work

Comment: Sorry - my bad.  I misread it due to the formatting.  Now it's been tidied up I can see that.  Thanks :)

Comment: I verified it.. jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gauravpandeyuit/Pmqe3/1/ . The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.  http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: This is the answer indeed, how you can break your head over such a small change :) Thank you

Comment: @Bigalow: Don't worry, once you have fought the DOM million years, your head won't break :)